# Excel - need this to return unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need the following working code to count only unique values:

`=COUNTIF('App and Server Detail Merge'!$F:$F,"Card")`

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is a bit unclear. If you can provide sample, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a row column with no data. Imagine that your data starts with A2 and goes down. In B2 write this formula:

`=COUNTIF(A1:$A$1, A2)`

then copy and paste that all the way down the B column. In the C column write an IF statement that will only look for values in the B column that are "0" and return the value in the A column. Here's an example:

`=IF(B2=0,A2,"")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why amo deleted his suggestion, that looks like a good start point. You don't say which column holds the data to count so assuming you want a count of different items in `A2:A100` where the same row in column F has the text "card":

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(F2:F100="card",IF(A2:A100<>"",MATCH(A2:A100,A2:A100,0))),ROW(A2:A100)-ROW(A2)+1),1))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You can expand the ranges as required but it's not a good idea to use whole columns as that will make the formula quite slow